# How to build a NSPredicate for fetching a relationship in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a data model like this:

```
Section      <----->>  SubSection
(subSections)          (section)
```

Now I want to fetch all SubSections for a given section. In Objective C I would have done it in this way:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"section == %@",
                        self.sectionObject];
```

In Swift I tried

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "section == %@", arguments: self.sectionObject)
```

(The `FetchRequest` is configured for the entity `SubSection`.)

But this results in a compiler error `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSPredicate' with an argument list of type '(format: String, arguments: NSManagedObject?)'`

I know I could do it like this:

```
let sectionName: String = self.sectionObject!.valueForKey("name") as! String
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "section.name == %@", argumentArray: [sectionName])
```

But as far as I recall from the Apple Documentation this is not very performant and so it is not recommended.

So how it is done properly in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both

```
NSPredicate(format: "section == %@", arguments: [self.sectionObject])
NSPredicate(format: "section == %@", self.sectionObject)
```

should work. The first passes the values for the predicate as an array, the second
as a variable argument list.

Comment: I don’t know why but first it didn’t work. After copying your code in my project it worked like charm.

Comment: @RayWojciechowski: In your code `NSPredicate(format: "section == %@", arguments: self.sectionObject)` the square brackets for the array are missing.

Comment: Ah! Now I see it. Thank you very much! :)